# Finding min, max, avg in Pandas, Python for all rows with the same first column

Tags: python, pandas, max, average, min

Is it possible to find minimum, maximum and average value of all data with a same first column?

For example, for first column `1_204192587`:

1. take into account all rows and columns from 4 to n
2. find min, max and avg of all entries in columns 4+ and all rows with `**1_204192587**` value in first column.

   Meaning, to do kind of describing data for every unique Start value shown below.

> ```
>  `In: data.groupby(["Start"]).groups.keys()
>
>  out: dict_keys(['1_204192587', '1_204197200'])`
> ```

[This is how data frame looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJOvc.png)

I tried

```
df=data.groupby(["Start"]).describe()
```

But This is not what I want.

I also try to specify axis while describing,

```
data.apply.(pd.DataFrame.describe, axis=1)
```

but I got error.

Desired output

```
unique key/first column value   MIN   MAX   AVG
 1_204192587                    *     *      *
 1_204197200                    *     *      *
```

I am a beginner, thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want compare all numeric columns per groups, so convert `Start` column to `index`, then select numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last use [`DataFrameGroupBy.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html) by index:

```
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'Start':list('aaabbb')
})
df1 = data.set_index("Start").select_dtypes(np.number).stack().groupby(level=0).describe() 
print (df1)
       count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
Start                                                      
a       12.0  5.000000  2.256304  1.0  3.75  5.0  6.25  9.0
b       12.0  3.833333  2.516611  0.0  2.00  4.0  5.00  9.0
```

Or specify list of aggregate functions by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = (data.set_index("Start")
           .select_dtypes(np.number)
           .stack()
           .groupby(level=0)
           .agg(['min','max','mean']))
print (df2)
       min  max      mean
Start                    
a        1    9  5.000000
b        0    9  3.833333
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below:

```py
df.loc[4:].describe()
```

`df` is your dataframe 
`[4:]` chooses the 5th row and on 
`.describe()` gives you a statistical summary (avg, mean ...)

You can also add `.transpose()` and the end to get the output you asked.

And if you want to assign it to another variable(dataframe)

so it will look like:

```py
new_df = df.loc[4:].describe().trasnpose()
```